# After posting I can't see my tweet on timeline

Tags: twitter

After posting a tweet from computer or phone,  I can't see in **Tweets** but I can see it in **Tweets & Replies**.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Is it happening for all the tweets or for one tweet? What about retweets, are you able to see whatever you retweet on your timeline? are you able to see those people's tweets on your timeline whom you are following?
Try login from other browser or clear the cache of your current browser. If you are using App, uninstall and install it again. Then check.

Comment: No. it is not happening with all tweets.. i tried to tweet with photo but it does not show on my **timeline in tweet** section, but showing on **timeline in tweet & replies** section... But i tweet with simple message hi then it is showing to me.

Comment: Looks like your data is not refreshing. Try to do this: login from other browser or clear the cache of your current browser. If you are using App, uninstall and install it again. Then check.

Comment: i tried from another browser but still situation is same. i uninstall and install my app and i tried still same situation.

Comment: when i tweet with simple message hie or else , then it is showing on my timeline

Comment: Is the tweet you can't see in your Tweets section a new tweet or a reply to another tweet?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and just found that if your tweet starts with "@" it will not show on the timeline. So either start with a "." before the handle or rephrase.

The assumption being you are engaged in a conversation w/ someone. This was not the case, I was quoting someone in a webinar.

Answer (score 2):

If you retweet your tweet, it will appear on your timeline.

Answer (score 0):

If you tweet an image with no text/comment, you get the behavior you are describing.
Also, it is important to remember that #hashtags and @usernames don't count as text in a comment, so you have to put some actuall text in the comment.  For example...

> @BarnyardSushi #doodle #Tucson

The above will show up in your "Tweets and replies" (but not in "Tweets").  However...

> @BarnyardSushi #doodle, #Tucson

will show up in both places.

Answer (score -1):

Try opening your twitter on Ingognito mode and then tweet it again.. It will be done.
Also clear your cache memory

Answer (score -1):

If you tweet anything which starts with @xyz... then it will not be shown in your timeline. Instead it will show up under ""Tweets and replies..... Workaround: Use @xyz in then end after writing something.

Answer (score -1):

It will show only show under Tweets & replies and not under Tweets when both factors below are met:

> Your Tweet starts with "@" or mentioning the user.
> You're following the user that you mentioned in the Tweet

Already tested this from my end. Hope it helps :)